# Hair grow or hair grows

Tags: grammaticality, singular-vs-plural, grammatical-number

Which form is correct:

> My hair grow slowly

or

> My hair grows slowly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My hair grows slowly

I think hair is used idiomatically as an uncountable noun. It means hairs collectively.

Comment: It's actually hair collectively. Your answer is right but the explanation is funny to a native speaker. :)